# Finding a 1-form which projects vectors onto a certain line and scales to a certain factor?

Tags: vectors, differential-forms

I'm working through Bachman's "A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms" and need a sanity check on one of the exercises. In Chapter 1, Exercise 2.2 it ask,...

> Find a 1-form which projects vectors onto the line $dy = 2dx$ and scales by a factor of 2.

So my attempt at a solution is to find a vector on the line y = 2x that is 2 times longer than the unit vector and I get$<\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}>$. Is this what the question is asking for? Is there something I'm missing? I tried to find a unit vector on that line and found $<\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}>$ and feel pretty confident about that part. I figured the scaling should just be multiplying that vector by the scalar $2$. It's been a while since vector calculus and I haven't encountered a problem in a while that was asked quite like this one. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the proper way to answer this question like such,... $\omega = \frac{4}{\sqrt(5)}dx + \frac{2}{\sqrt(5)}dy$ is the 1-form which projects vectors onto the line $dy = 2dx$ and scales by a factor of 2.

Comment: I don't even understand the question. The line should be $y=2x$; why are there $d$'s? Next, by the projection onto a line, does the author mean the *signed length* of that projection? You won't get a vector answer unless you do something fancier.

Comment: that's exactly how the author says it in the text. Here's the textbook https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306194